# Show/Hide page parts based on own/foreign profile

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I am building a social network and I can not figure out the best way to solve this problem:

E.g. for profile page - what is the best way to show/hide different parts of profile page based on friendship status of two users, or based on the fact if user is viewing his own or foreign profile.

Is it OK to have presentation logic in VIEW? Something like

`<?php if ($logged_user_id==$viewed_profile_user_id) {echo "This is your profile"} ?>`

Or should all logic for displaying "view parts" (images, statuses, user friends, etc..) be in controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question when you typed *"Is it OK to have presentation logic in VIEW?"* If it's presentation logic, of course it belong in the presentation layer. The business logic should determine *what* you can see, and in which level of detail - the presentation should decide *how* to present it.

As for the friends example, this is part of the business logic (fetch the friends list of not). It should also set a flag like "ConnectionLevel", and then the presentation logic can decide whether it has no friends list because you are not a direct connection, or because the user actually has no friends, and base its output on that.

Comment: Yes thanks... the "presentation logic" in my answer should be "business logic" of course. So you are saying, that all business logic - to show or not to show some parts of the page, should be in controller?

Comment: No, it should present **usable** data to the view. It should determine the connection level, and then let the view decide how to display the result best based on that data. In some cases yes, the business logic can provide flags like `CanSeeFriends` to the presentation logic, or `IsOwnProfile`, but the code in your example should then definitely be in the View (the output based on the data).